# Flex lexical analyzer rule not matching error

Tags: regex, flexbox, flex-lexer, lexical

```
%option noinput nounput
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cool.tab.h"
int lineNo = 1;
%}

%s class_t inherits_t semi_t

NEWLINE     (\r\n|\n)
WHITESPACE  [ \t]+
DIGIT    [0-9]

%%

                
{WHITESPACE}    /* SKIP */
{NEWLINE}       { lineNo++; }

"("     { return LPAREN; }
")"     { return RPAREN; }
"{"     { return LBRACE; }
"}"     { return RBRACE; }
"<="    { return LTE; }
"<-"    { return ASSIGN; }
"<"     { return LT; }
"=>"    { return DARROW; }
"="     { return EQUAL; }
","     { return COMMA; }
";"     { return SEMICOLON; }
":"     { return COLON; }
"."     { return DOT; }
"+"     { return PLUS; }
"-"     { return MINUS; }
"*"     { return MUL; }
"/"     { return DIV; }
"~"     { return NEG; }
"@"     { return ATSIGN; }

(?-i:class)      { return CLASS; }
(?-i:inherits)   { return INHERITS; }
(?-i:new)   { return NEW; }
(?-i:if)   { return IF; }
(?-i:then)   { return THEN; }
(?-i:else)   { return ELSE; }
(?-i:fi)   { return FI; }
(?-i:while)   { return WHILE; }
(?-i:loop)   { return LOOP; }
(?-i:pool)   { return POOL; }
(?-i:let)   { return LET; }
(?-i:in)   { return IN; }
(?-i:case)   { return CASE; }
(?-i:of)   { return OF; }
(?-i:esac)   { return ESAC; }
(?-i:new)   { return NEW; }
(?-i:not)   { return NOT; }
(?-i:isvoid)   { return ISVOID; }
(?-i:true)   { return TRUE; }
(?-i:false)   { return FALSE; }

[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]* { return ID; }
{DIGIT}+ { return INTEGER; }

"class " { BEGIN(class_t); }
"inherits " { BEGIN(inherits_t); }
": " { BEGIN(semi_t); }

\"(\\.|[^"\\])*\"  { return STRING; }

<class_t,inherits_t,semi_t>[A-Z][A-Za-z_]* { return TYPE; }

%%
```

Hi, I was trying to make a lexical analyzer using flex and made rules here from defined keywords in the header file to strings, integer, identifier, and type using start conditions.
But when I compile it, I get rule cannot be matched error in line in line 61 and 76
which is

(?-i:not)   { return NOT; }      and
<class_t,inherits_t,semi_t>[A-Z][A-Za-z_]* { return TYPE; }

Could someone please help me with what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Either you or flex counted line 61 wrong. The unusable rule is the line before the one you indicate:

```
(?-i:new)   { return NEW; }
```

which also appears as the third keyword rule.

It's highly recommended that you write your keyword rules in alphabetic order, making it easy to avoid this sort of error. Also, if you want your keyword rules to be case **i**nsensitive, you need to turn that option on for the pattern by nesting it inside `(?i:...)`; `(?-i:` turns the case insensitive option off (in other words, makes the inner pattern case sensitive). That's the default, so those flag changes do nothing.

The other pattern identified as unmatchable is:

```
<class_t,inherits_t,semi_t>[A-Z][A-Za-z_]* { return TYPE; }
```

The problem here is that the start conditions are all declared with `%s`, which makes them *inclusive*, rather than `%x`, which would make them *exclusive*. An exclusive start condition only includes rules explicitly marked with that start condition's name, while an inclusive start condition also includes all rules not marked explicitly with any start condition. That  includes the earlier rule

```
[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]* { return ID; }
```

I guess you want those start conditions to be inclusive (but that's just a guess; you need to ensure that was your intention.) So you need to write your rules so that the rule which returns `TYPE` takes precedence. Either move that rule up so that it comes before the unmarked rule, or change the unmarked rule to explicitly apply on in the `<INITIAL>` start condition. (Or so that it doesn't apply in the other start conditions, using a negative marker.)

Either way, you need to ensure that the scanner returns to the `INITIAL` start condition; that never happens automatically.

If the only purpose of the start conditions is to return `CLASS` instead of `ID`, then they are unnecessary; the grammar should be able to figure that out without two different non-terminals. But perhaps you have some other motivation for the start conditions.